# add automatically value to column database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**notes** use rails 5.2 and postgresql

I have `Foluser` model contains `name`,`email`,`password`,`id_watch`

I need  when admin add new foluser

1. generate `password`

   when admin create new **foluser** generate `password` like   [Secure Password Generator](https://passwordsgenerator.net/)
2. get `id_watch` from `admin` model and put it to `id_watch` from `Foluser` model

   Admin`when register enter`username`,`email`,`password`,`id_watch`

   in point 2 need take this id_watch and save it in `user` model .

> admin only create foluser

```
`
class FolusersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_foluser, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :new , :create, :edit]

  # GET /folusers
  # GET /folusers.json
  def index
    @folusers = current_master.foluser.all

    #render json: @folusers

  end

  # GET /folusers/1
  # GET /folusers/1.json
  def show
    #@folusers = Foluser.where(master_id: @master.id).order("created_at DESC")

    #@foluser = Foluser.find(params[:id])
        #render json: @foluser



  end

  # GET /folusers/new
  def new
    @foluser = current_master.foluser.build
  end

  # GET /folusers/1/edit
  def edit
    #render json: @foluser
  end

  # POST /folusers
  # POST /folusers.json
  def create
    @foluser = current_master.foluser.build(foluser_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @foluser.save
        format.html { redirect_to @foluser, notice: 'Foluser was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @foluser }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @foluser.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /folusers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /folusers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @foluser.update(foluser_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @foluser, notice: 'Foluser was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @foluser }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @foluser.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /folusers/1
  # DELETE /folusers/1.json
  def destroy
    @foluser.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to folusers_url, notice: 'Foluser was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_foluser
      @foluser = Foluser.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def foluser_params
      params.require(:foluser).permit(:name, :email, :numberphone, :password)
    end
end
```

`foluser` model

```
class Foluser < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :admin, :optional => true
end
```

`admin` model

```
class Master < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :foluser
end
```

Comment: I hope you're not storing a `password` in plain text??!! If so, that's a **big** security vulnerability.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `ruby-on-rails-3` and `ruby-on-rails-4`? Which version are you actually using? (Is it actually `v5.x`?)

Comment: What have you tried so far? *Show us your code*. I would presume (but cannot know anything for certain without more info!) that you wish to perform this record creation from a *controller*, and that the *currently logged-in user* is the `Admin` from which you wish to set the `id_watch`? Possibly you've mis-described the situation, and it's actually the `admin`'s `id` that you wish to set as the `foluser`'s `id_watch`? (In which case, I'd rather use a more conventional and descriptive column name, like `creator_id`.

Comment: And lastly, please elaborate on what you mean by "generate `password`". What rules/format do you want to apply to the random string? (Any character/length requirements?) Do you want to reference the value later, e.g. in an email? Should this be considered a permanent, or temporary password? As mentioned above, should this be encrypted (probably!), or do you have a good reason to store the password unencrypted?

Comment: Thanks @TomLord for response i updated my question  and add more information .

Comment: Rails 5 has implemented a very clean `Attributes API` https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+5+attributes+api&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: You haven't really clarified the problem, if anything you've made it less clear... *"Admin when register enter `username`, `email`, `password`, `id_watch`"* -- So You **don't** want to randomly generate the password; you want to let the admin enter it?? (Or do you want the random generator to be done via JavaScript in the front-end?) And you also want to let the admin manually enter `id_watch`?? (I thought that value came from the `Admin` model?) And comment below, you mentioned a desire to store the password encrypted, with a `password_digest` attribute; how does this fit into your question?

Comment: Please explain, clearly, in full: What user flow are you trying to build here? I could provide an answer, but it would be a complete guess as to what you're trying to achieve, and would likely not be accurate. What columns are in the `admins` table? What columns are in the `folusers` table? How/where do you want to populate these values from?

Comment: Admin table can `sign up` , `login` , add `folusers` , view of position of  your watch device  and view The speed of the heartbeat of watch device . every admin can add folusers . foluser can  `login`, view   position and  speed of the heart

Comment: foluser can `login`, view position and speed of the heartbeat of admin watch

Comment: @Sdadad Ohhhh, so `id_watch` is actually the foreign key for a `watches` table!! In that case the convention would be to call it `watch_id`, not `id_watch`. You still haven't really addressed the key questions, though -- Is `id_watch` (or better-named, `watch_id`) an attribute of the admin? Or does the admin *choose* which watch to create a new user for? And as I keep saying, I don't know what you're trying to achieve with this `password`, exactly... Should it be generated in the front-end, or the back-end? Is it "temporary" or "permanent"? Do you need to read it in plain-text?

Comment: In other words, are you trying to do: `foluser.id_watch == admin.id_watch`? Or does the admin select the watch from a dropdown, when creating the `foluser`? (This is why I asked you "what columns are in each table?" - but you haven't provided that information yet.)

Comment: admin contain `username`,`email`,`password`,`id_watch`,`numberphone`. folsuer contain `username`,`email`,`password`,`id_watch``numberphone`,`id_master`

Comment: (`numberphone`? Why not `phone_number`?) So the `foluser` is being created in an action like `FoluserController#create`? Where is your code for the controller? Can you do something like: `foluser.id_watch = current_user.id_watch`? Or maybe the `foluser`s are created by some other means, e.g. a CSV file upload? Can you [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51014282/edit) with all of this information -- including, crucially, what you've written so far?

Comment: ok i edit post and all information ?

Comment: @TomLord can view edit post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current code, setting the `id_watch` can be done here in the controller:

```
class FolusersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @foluser = current_master.folusers.build(foluser_params)

    @foluser.id_watch = current_master.id_watch # <-- !!!

    respond_to do |format|
      if @foluser.save
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Despite our extended conversation above, I'm still unclear what you're trying to achieve with the "password generation".

(Should it be generated in the front-end, or the back-end? Should it be stored encrypted, or in plain text? If encrypted, do you need to be able to reverse this encryption? Is it a "permanent" password, or a "temporary" password? ...)

Therefore, the following code should be taken with a big pinch of salt - since I still don't really know what the desired/correct behaviour is.

In the `FolusersController`, you've defined the following method:

```
def foluser_params
  params.require(:foluser).permit(:name, :email, :numberphone, :password)
end
```

However, if you want the password to be *generated* by the server then you shouldn't be allowing the `admin` to set the password through the controller. Therefore, remove this parameter:

```
def foluser_params
  params.require(:foluser).permit(:name, :email, :numberphone)
end
```

And then somewhere - perhaps in the controller, or as a hook in the model - set this password to something random:

```
class FolusersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @foluser = current_master.folusers.build(foluser_params)
    @foluser.password = SecureRandom.hex(10 + rand(6))
    # ...
   end
end

# or

class Foluser < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize :default_password

  def default_password
    self.password ||= SecureRandom.hex(10 + rand(6))
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomlord why need generate password when admin add Foluser generate password automatically  and send this password to foluser. permanent" password, or a "temporary" password? yes is temporary password . stored encrypted or not yes no encrypted if you have any resource explain that please tell me . if you need more information can give it . Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you found the solution, use rails callbacks in your model to extract this kind of logic from the controller.

But I'd rather use `after_initialize` than `before_save` so that you won't set a default password before each save(so possibly even update action)

Then use things like SecureRandom (ActiveSupport concern) (already bundled by rails, no requires required)

```
after_initialize :defaultpassword
...
def default_password
  self.password ||= SecureRandom.hex(10 + rand(6))
end
```

not the best way to do random I know but feel free to customize it.

secure_random output examples:

```
=>bf8d42b174d297f6460eef
=>efd28869171a1ec89c3438
=>3855c61fb6b90ed549d777
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexisDelahaye this success and solve problem for password. can help to second problem ?

Comment: This ignores the big security vulnerability that you're storing the password in plain-text. You should almost never do this.

Comment: I know @TomLord i use many method for encryption and not store in plain text .  know shouldn't store password plain text Because of many problems . i read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html .